# How can I make Matrix Rain?

Tags: unity, shaders

I want to make 3d Matrix rain like [this shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4t3BWl) that you can rotate camera.I tried to convert this shader but It have many calculations that it's expensive inside game engine.then I tried to make this effect by trail Renderer but I couldn't make random letters inside trail renderer.finally I tried by Instantiating quads but It hadn't fade like trail.

so my question is how can I make this effect In efficient way?

Comment: this question is a bit too open-ended for stack exchange